# why sizeof("") is equivalent to 1 and sizeof(NULL) is equivalent to 4 in c-language?

Tags: c

why `sizeof("")` is equivalent to 1 and `sizeof(NULL)` is equivalent to 4  in c-language ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A string literal is an **array** of characters* (with static storage), which contains all the characters in the literal along with a terminator. The size of an array is the size of the element multiplied by the number of elements in the array.

The literal `""` is an array that consists of one `char` with the value `0`. The type is `char[1]`, and `sizeof(char)` is always one; therefore`sizeof(char[1])` is always one.

In C, `NULL` is implementation-defined, and is often `((void*)0)`. The size of a `void*`, *on your particular implementation*, is 4. It may be a different number depending on the platform you run on. `NULL` may also expand to an integer of some type of the value 0, and you'd get the size of that instead.

*A literal is not a pointer, arrays are not pointers, pointers do not play a role in this part of the question.

Comment: `NULL` is an implementation-defined null pointer constant, it is not required to be `((void*)0)`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 14):

The empty string `""` has type `char[1]`, or "array 1 of `char`".  It is *not* a pointer, as most people believe.  It can *decay* into a pointer, so any time a pointer to `char` is expected, you can use an array of `char` instead, and the array will decay into a pointer to its first element.

Since `sizeof(char)` is 1 (by definition), we therefore have `sizeof("")` is `sizeof(char[1])`, which is 1*1 = 1.

In C, `NULL` is an "implementation-defined null pointer constant" (C99 §7.17.3).  A "null pointer constant" is defined to be an integer expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *` (C99 §6.3.2.3.3).  So the actual value of `sizeof(NULL)` is implementation-defined: you might get `sizeof(int)`, or you might get `sizeof(void*)`.  On 64-bit systems, you often have `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(void*) == 8`, which means *you can't depend on what `sizeof(NULL)` is*.

Also note that most C implementations define `NULL` as `((void*)0)` (though this is not required by the standard), whereas most C++ implementations just define `NULL` as a plain `0`.  **This means that the value of `sizeof(NULL)` can and will change depending on if code is compiled as C or as C++** (for example, code in header files shared between C and C++ source files).  So do not depend on `sizeof(NULL)`.

Comment: I believe that "an integer expression" is not necessarily of type `int` - both `0L` and `0LL` would also be conforming definitions of `NULL`, so you might get `sizeof(long)` or `sizeof(long long)` too (or perhaps even the size of some implementation-defined integer type that's even wider!).

Answer (score 6):

NULL in C is defined as (void*)0. Since it's a pointer, it takes 4 bytes to store it. And, "" is 1 byte because that "empty" string has EOL character ('\0').

Comment: "[on some implementations] it takes 4 bytes to store it".

Comment: 4 bytes for a pointer is a function of the architecture. I've used systems where it was 2 or 8. Or 1 12-bit machine word. Probably the OP is using x86, but don't feel that you can assume that...

Comment: NULL is not defined by C to anything but "implementation-defined null pointer constant" (C99 §7.17.3). On some OS, compiler, platform, phase of the moon, it can be 0 without cast to void*. No guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

sizeof(NULL) is not nothing, but a pointer to the address 0, and a pointer on a 32 bit system takes 4 bytes.

Comment: <pedantic> `NULL` is the integer constant 0 casted to a `void *` in C. However, that's allowed to be represented at the machine level as values other than zero. If a compiler wanted the hardware-level null pointer to point to `0xDEADBEEF` it would be perfectly valid, but that would still be represented in code as the integer constant `0`.

Answer (score 0):

"" --> Cstrings are terminated by convention with a x'00' null character so literal "" consists of one character x'00' and has sie of 1 byte.

NULL is by default a null pointer which on particular 32 bit machines has a size of four bytes on different platforms it could br 1,2,3,4,6 or 8. Maybe even 5 or 7 but I have never come accross a  40 bit or 56 bit addressing. Also in some older architectures there may be extra bits associated with a pointer to indicate data vs. instruction vs. device buffer storage etc.

Comment: I would upvote this if I could understand it through the sea of typos ;). One thing -- it might be beneficial to refer to `""` as a "null terminated character literal", otherwise in C++ land people can think you're referring to MFC's `CString` class.