# How is sizeof(*NULL) equal to 1 on 32-bit C compiler?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

I recently learned that `sizeof` is not a function and actually evaluates at compile time.

But I still haven't been able to figure out how `sizeof(*NULL)` is equal to 1.

EDIT: I'm talking about gcc here specifically.

Comment: Had to look it up myself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141666/why-sizeof-is-equivalent-to-1-and-sizeofnull-is-equivalent-to-4-in-c-langu

Comment: @Katianie - `sizeof(NULL)` and `sizeof(*NULL)` are very different things.

Comment: @Katianie Exactly, I have already read that post and couldn't find a reference for sizeof(*NULL)

Comment: I think `sizeof(void)` is a GNU - specific extension

Comment: NULL is also different depending on platform, OS, and language (c vs c++)

Comment: Normally, pointer arithmetic on void-pointers are undefined behaviour. The reason sort of has to do with this quesion - the size of void is normally not defined (it is in GCC though, as nwellnhof mentions)

Comment: `*NULL` is an error. It should produce at least a compiler warning, and there's no reason to think it has any meaning.

Comment: Are you asking out of idle curiosity?  The question, though nominally answerable, has zero practical application...

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker True, but I am talking about *NULL in the context of sizeof.

Comment: Size of an error is not an error? *NULL doesn't even have a type, how could it have a value or a size? It's meaningless, a non-entity. "NULL" specifically means "I don't point to anything", then you're asking the size of the thing it points to. That the compiler produces anything is a surprise.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker And yet it produces output as 1!    https://ideone.com/9WPvRe

Comment: @UtkarshAgarwal *And yet it produces output as 1* That's a GCCism that violates **6.2.5 Types**, paragraph 19 of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):  "The
`void`
type  comprises  an  empty  set  of  values;  **it  is  an  incomplete  object  type  that
cannot be completed.**"

Comment: Welcome to "undefined". Just because it's meaningless doesn't mean the compiler will necessarily fail, or generate an error. That would be too convenient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on the compiler and standard library. With GCC and glibc, `NULL` is defined as `(void*)0` and GCC has [an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html) that allows pointer arithmetic on `void` pointers using `sizeof(void) == 1`. Without this extension, the compiler would produce an error.

A standard library could also define `NULL` as `0`. In this case `sizeof(*NULL)` would also be illegal.

Answer (score 3):

Standard makes no guarantee as to the value returned by `sizeof(*NULL)`, which is enough to not use this construct in practice.

Your code uses implementation-defined behavior.

> 7.173 The macros are
>
> ```
> NULL
> ```
>
> which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant

This means that the standard does not guarantee that your code is going to compile, let alone producing a certain value.

On systems defining macro `NULL` as `((void*)0)` your code will trigger a warning that should be treated as an error:

> prog.c:4:28: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to a void type [-Werror=pointer-arith]

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/J8ZzP1)

Comment: There is no valid definition of `NULL` for which `sizeof(*NULL)` is not a constraint violation. `NULL` can be an constant integer expression with the value zero (in which case dereferencing a non-pointer is invalid) *or* such an expression cast to `void*` (in which case `*NULL` is of type `void`, which has no size). If `sizeof(*NULL)` does not trigger at least a warning, then your compiler is non-conforming -- as gcc is by default.

Answer (score 2):

Since `NULL` has type `void *`, that would mean `*NULL` has type `void`.  Taking the size of `void` is not allowed by the C standard, although some compilers do as an extension.

In [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html), it treats the size of `void` as 1 to allow pointer arithmetic on `void *`.

Comment: The C standard doesn't mandate that `NULL` is of type `void *`. It can also be an integer constant expression with the value 0. For example `#define NULL (2*4-8)` would be legal.

Comment: @EugeneSh. From the C spec: *An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant.* If the integer 0 is converted to a pointer, it may not map to the address 0, though. Also see the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/null/varieties.html).

Comment: @nwellnhof I have happened to work with a system where the address `0` was a valid address. Still don't know how to handle that though :)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The definition of a null pointer constant is basically about its syntax, not about how it's represented. An implementation might use all-bits-one to represent a null pointer at run time, but converting the integer constant `0` to `void*` must still yield a null pointer value. On most implementations, a null pointer is represented as all-bits-zero, so the conversion is trivial (perhaps with a size adjustment). On other implementations, the conversion has to do some work to get the right result.

Answer (score 1):

On "old time" NULL was defined as:

```
#define NULL ((char *)0)
```

so with `*NULL` you get a char, which has size of 1. (You can still see such definition hidden in headers, as fall back case, now, starting with C90, the `char` is substituted with `void`).

I do not think it is a valid code (indirection of NULL, also just to take the size).

On some compilers null is `0l` or just `0`, which will give an error in your case.

Comment: Where did you see such a definition?

Comment: If it was defined like that, any simple assignment to another pointer type would be problematic.

Comment: Ok, this was the old C, now it is either  `((void *) 0)` or `0` (it is incredible how many includes has `NULL` defined on a normal system.

Comment: @StoryTeller: what? `char` was always special, and `void` is a relatively recent addition in C.

Comment: @EugeneSh. On Debian code, there are some references of such definition, and some definition are wrong, but anyway: https://sources.debian.org/src/bash/4.4.18-1.1/lib/termcap/tparam.c/?hl=60#L60

Comment: 1989 (the first standard being published) is your definition of recent (in 2018)? Your assertions here, as far as the C languages specification goes, have been false longer than they have been true.

Comment: @StoryTeller: when I started to program free software, in late 90s, the C90 were not allowed (because not so portable on all systems). So I would say that half of C live were without void ;-)  But yeah. I should have verified better (I see that there were some cases still with char, and I didn't realized that `void*` is the correct way.

Comment: Maybe rephrase a bit: s/^Often/In some legacy software/ ?

Comment: That definition of `NULL` has been invalid (i.e., it would cause the implementation that provides it to be non-conforming) since the 1989 ANSI C standard.